# Chrome extension runtime onInstalled vs onStartup event order

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My questions is regarding the startup order of the two events `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` and `chrome.runtime.onStartup` when Chrome was updated and restarted. Does `onInstalled` fire when Chrome is updated and before getting restarted, or after Chrome is restarted but after `onStartup`

- `onInstalled` is fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version.
- `onStartup` is fired when Chrome is starting up.

Comment: @wOxxOm I rephrased my question since the wording was confusing.

Comment: onInstalled definitely fires after Chrome is restarted (note the past tense), but the order of onStartup/onInstalled is not documented so if it'll change in the future you shouldn't be taken by surprise.